# What is the Item in a nested struct that implements the Iterator trait?

Tags: rust, iterator, nested-lists

I am watching [a video on Rust iterators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yozQ9C69pNs) and the video host implements a slightly more complex struct `Flatten`. In essence, this `Flatten` struct holds items, each of which implements the `IntoIterator` trait so that each item inside `Flatten` (*Note that the following code is not the final code from the video and is only used to show my confusion*):

```rust
pub struct Flatten<O>
{
    outer: O,
}

impl<O> Flatten<O> {
    fn new(iter: O) -> Self {
        Flatten { outer: iter }
    }
}
```

Then there is the part where `Flatten` implements the `Iterator` trait:

```rust
impl<O> Iterator for Flatten<O>
where
    O: Iterator,
    O::Item: IntoIterator,
{
    type Item = <O::Item as IntoIterator>::Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.outer.next().and_then(|inner| inner.into_iter().next())
    }
}
```

What I am very confused about is that when we set the constraint `O::Item: IntoIterator`, we obviously meant that the generic type `O` has items that implement `IntoIterator`.

**Edit 1:** To clarify, my confusion was that we first said that `O::Item: IntoIterator` and then specified again `type Item = <O::Item as IntoIterator>::Item`. Are the `Item`s appearing in these two clauses referring to different concepts?

**Edit 2:** I think I understand it now. An `Iterator` has `Item`, so we could write `O::Item: IntoIterator`. And when we define `type Item = <O::Item as IntoIterator>::Item`, we are specifying the return Item type for `Flatten`, not for `O`. I was confused by the syntax and had some illogical understanding.

Comment: I don't see the issue, you never refer to a bare `Item`, always a `Self::Item`, `O::Item` or `<O::Item as IntoIterator>::Item`. No ambiguity.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding this question, in particular "Is an `Item` in `Flatten` still `O` or is it now `Flatten::O::Item`?" What exactly is "an `Item` in `Flatten`"? And why should it be `O`? And what is `Flatten::O::Item` supposed to be? It would be nice if you could clarify the question.

Comment: The implementation of `Flatten` does something rather weird, by the way, and I certainly wouldn't call that operation "flattening".

Comment: @SvenMarnach This isn't the final implementation, the host points out the mistake later in the video. OP could have included that in the question though..

Comment: @NiklasMohrin I made an edit to specify that now. Thanks.

Comment: @rodrigo @SvenMarnach My confusion was that we first said that `O::Item: IntoIterator` and then specified again `type Item = <O::Item as IntoIterator>::Item`. Are the `Items` appearing in these two clauses different?

Comment: Yes, they are different. You have iterators of iterators, thing of the `Item` of `Vec<Vec<i32>>` vs the `Item` of `Vec<i32>`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I just realized where my logical loophole is in reading the syntax. Now I understand why none of you see the issue nor my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust knows what item to chose because we specifically tell him what `Item` to chose.
We know that both `Iterator` and `IntoIterator` define an `Item`.

So `Flatten` is a collection of other `IntoIterator` (`O`) , being the target to access this IntoIterator inner items we need to set the `Flatten::Item` to be the same as the inner `IntoIterator::Item`, hence:

`type Item = <O::Item as IntoIterator>::Item;`

Since we are implementing `Iterator` the `Self::Item` is that implementation-defined item (the inner ones that we just explained).

As recap:

- `O::Item` => Inner `IntoIterator::Item` for flatten
- `Self::Item` => Flatten as Iterator `Item`. Which matches the previous one.
- `Flatten::Item` => Same as `Self::Item` for the `Iterator` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped me to see that I had an obvious logical loophole in my reading of the syntax.